# Visual Studio Team Services: new project binds to old projects bindings

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have managed to confuse Visual Studio Team Services.

In VSTS I have multiple projects for different clients.
Each Client has multiple solutions.

I have copied a couple of web projects, using them as a base for other work, and made changes to them independently..

That has confused TFS and now some of my projects (and all their history) are now missing from Visual Studio Team Services..

I have the current code on my development machine.

In an effort to rectify this i thought i would simply copy the solutions to a new subdirectory, delete the vss files, update the guids and reload into Visual Studio Team Services - well that didn't work :-(

**So with explicit detail, here are the steps I followed:**

I copied (using explorer) a project that existed in TFS to a new SubDirectory of the main SCCS directory.

I then renamed the original projects root folder (using explorer)

I then (in the new projects folder) deleted the .vss and .vssscc files and the .vs directory

I generated a new GUID inside of Visual Studio 2015

I opened the .sln file (in notepad) and:
replaced the project guid in the the Project line and the ProjectConfigurationPlatforms Lines with the new GUID and 
Removed the GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl).

I then deleted the files and emptied the Recycle Bin for the following directories

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache

When i opened the new project in visual studio, some the files were marked as still being in TFS with a green tick.

I went to file-> SourceControl-> advanced and unbound both the project and the solution, saved and closed.

This also removed source control form the original project!

Then reopened the new solution, connected to Visual Studio Team Services, connected to the team project for this specific client

I went to file-> SourceControl-> advanced and bound both the project and the solution to Source Control.

Then in the Pending Changes Section, in the Excluded Changes section, it lists all the files of the original project!

And in the Included Changes includes a file that is not in the solution explorer..

Can anyone let me know what step i have missed as this should be a simple task - surely.

Is there another cache somewhere to delete?

Do i need to delete the solutions in Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update project files: Remove

```
  <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Simple steps:

1. Copy solution folder to other place that not included in any workspaces
2. Delete *.vspscc files and .vs folder
3. Edit .sln file to remove GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)… section
4. Edit project files to remove `<Scc….>` sections

BTW: you don’t need to update project GUID.

Comment: Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately its a web project and doesn't have a project file 
- can you be a bit more explicit 
- I have checked hidden files

Comment: Ahh the first point might be the key: 
Copy solution folder to other place that not included in any workspaces
Let me try that..

Comment: Ignore my first comment - the SAK references are in the Solution File in the WebsiteProperties Section

Comment: No Luck, I even renamed the project in the solution file and directories in the new folder outside of the SCCS workspace :-(
When i add the project to SourceControl, it must be still linking it to the old project somehow

Comment: @TheTimp Regarding website, is website path the absolute path?(check sln file) If so you need to update website path in solution file. (e.g. Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath)

Answer (score 0):

After chatting to Microsoft Support it turns out that we had been doing everything right, as per "starain-MSFT"'s concise guide below, but the final add to Source Control step by opening the solution and right clicking add to source control had issues.

The approach i ended up using is:

1. Copy solution folder to other place that not included in any workspaces (I also renamed the project at this point)
2. Delete *.vspscc files and .vs folder
3. Edit .sln file / project files to remove  sections
4. Edit .sln file to remove GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)… section

At this point I also created a new project guid and inserted that into the Project and GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms)... sections.

Then what worked for me was opening Visual Studio, then opening the source Safe Explorer (View Other Windows-> Source Safe Explorer) and choosing Add Items to folder

Thanks starain-MSFT for your help.